# Capturing numbers in Lakhs and Crores on Google Assistant - Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am building a chat-bot using dialogflow and webhook (nodejs). I want to run this chatbot on Google Assistant. The problem that I am facing is that if a person says "1.5 [Lakhs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh)" or "22 lacs", google assistant does not convert it to 150 000 or 2 200 000 respectively.

I have created an intent named "get-customer-income" on dialogflow with some training phrases

[image: Training Phrases]

Dialog flow automatically got the parameters as sys.number and denom

[image]

which is an entity I created

[image]

I then routed it thru webhook to handle the denom entity as follows

```js
app.intent('get-customer-income',(conv,{number,denom}) =>{
  const income = number;
  console.log(number,denom);
  var actualincome,denomination;
  if(denom ==='lakhs'){
    actualincome = income * 100000;
  } else if(denom === 'crore'){
    actualincome = income * 10000000;
  } else {
    actualincome = income;
  }
    conv.ask(`Your ${actualincome}`);
});
```

When I test it works fine on the Dialogflow chatbot simulator on the right panel

[image]

while it doesn't work when I test it on Google Assistant simulator

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution.
Instead of getting the parameters inside app.intent, I got the parameters using conv.parameters['parameterName']

Following is how my webhook looks now.

```
app.intent('get-customer-income',(conv) =>{
  const number = conv.parameters['number'];
  const denom = conv.parameters['denom'];
  const income = number;
  console.log(number,denom);
  var actualincome,denomination;
  if(denom ==='lakhs'){
    actualincome = income * 100000;
  } else if(denom === 'crore'){
    actualincome = income * 10000000;
  } else {
    actualincome = income;
  }
  conv.ask(`Your actual income is ${actualincome} ${denom}`);
});
```

I am aware that I have used way too many constants in this function which can be replaced. Although this works like a charm too!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is matching the training phrase without the `denom` parameter.

Since the `denom` parameter is optional, you probably don't need that training phrase at all. Try deleting it, retraining, and see how it matches.

Comment: denom is an entity I created to capture words like Lakh and lac. which I then detect and do the multiplication to arrive at the actual number in lac. 
If I remove the denom parameter in the phrase it will not detect it and won't work in dialogflow emulator. The problem is that the code works perfectly in dialogflow emulator but it doesnt work on the Actions on Google Emulator